# Wie sagt man "This is a reach" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

Auf ELL bin ich vorhin über die Phrase "This is a reach" gestolpert.

> Here - **and this is a reach** - but it could technically be understood to mean that my mother thinks this girl is the prettiest I can find, though there are prettier ones out there in general.

Seitdem überlege ich, wie man dies auf Deutsch ausdrückt. Mir schwebt ein ganz bestimmter Ausdruck im Sinne. Es liegt mir quasi auf der Zunge, nur will es mir dann doch nicht einfallen.
Ich hoffe, mir kann jemand beim Aha-Effekt helfen?

Zur Erläuterung: Die Phrase besagt im Wesentlichen, dass etwas höchst unwahrscheinlich ist (oder je nach Kontext schlicht übertrieben), jedoch nicht unbedingt ausgeschlossen.

Comment: "rein theoretisch", "das ist zugegebenermassen etwas weit hergeholt", "unwahrscheinlich", irgendwas mit "Deutung"?

Comment: @Emanuel You got it. "Das ist zugegebenermassen etwas *weit hergeholt*" ist was mir im Sinn schwebte. Mensch, ich kam einfach nicht mehr drauf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich kann mir vorstellen, dass man in solchen Sätzen Ergänzungen wie

> … da begebe ich mich auf dünnes Eis, aber …

oder auch

> … da lehne ich mich zwar weit aus dem Fenster, aber …

einschränkend nutzen kann.

Comment: `eine kühne Behauptung`